# How to effect players that triggered a command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to do a `/testfor` command for burning players, and then instantly heal them, what is the command for that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Or have you tried looking up how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, add an objective to track if a player is burning:

```
/scoreboard objectives add isBurning dummy
```

On a clock, run the following commands in this order:

```
/scoreboard players set @a isBurning 1 
/scoreboard players set @a isBurning 0 {Fire:-20s}
/effect @a[score_isBurning_min=1] instant_health 20 20
```

The way this works is that, first, everybody's `isBurning` score is set to 1. When not burning, a player's `Fire` tag is at `-20s`, so the `isBurning` score for those with a `Fire` tag at `-20s` is then set to 0, leaving only those who are burning still with an `isBurning` score of 1. The instant_health potion effect can then be applied to the players that are burning.

---

As a general tip, the `/testfor` command is a lot less useful than people seem to think. When using `/testfor`, you are essentially just asking "Does this entity exist?" and getting a yes/no answer without being able to do anything with the entity matched your query. If you want to be doing something with the entity (healing, killing, teleporting, etc.), you shouldn't use `/testfor`.

Comment: +1 for the general tip. Typically, execute is better suited. testfor has niche functionality for adventure maps, and is largely incompatible with fill clocks.

Comment: You should explicitly mention fill clocks, as the scoreboard commands need to run simultaneously but in order, so that the wscores don't fluctuate

Comment: @MrLemon It should be fine if they're not run simultaneously, so long as they're run in order.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in just one command in Minecraft 1.13:

```
/effect give @a[nbt=!{Fire:-20s}] instant_health 20 20
```